# Killing forked process in ruby with child processes

Tags: ruby

The following code forks the main processes and runs a command in backticks. The kill at the end of the script only kills the forked process but not it's child processes (i.e. the sleep command).

```ruby
pid = fork do
  Thread.new do
    `sleep 20`
  end
end
sleep(1)
Process.kill("HUP",pid)
```

Is there a way to kill all child processes (generated by backtick commands in threads in the forked process) other than searching through the process tree?

Answer (score 2):

> Behind the scene both system and backtick operations use fork to fork
>   the current process and then they execute the given operation using
>   exec .
>
> Since exec replaces the current process it does not return anything if
>   the operation is a success. If the operation fails then
>   `SystemCallError is raised.

http://blog.bigbinary.com/2012/10/18/backtick-system-exec-in-ruby.html

Comment: so I guess the answer then is no, you must search the process tree

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
pid = Process.spawn('sleep 20')
```

to get the PID of the process immediately.  Your code above would change to:

```
pid = Process.spawn('sleep 20')
sleep(1)
Process.kill('HUP',pid)
```